# Native interface and extention method, what's the diff in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

In .Net, we can acquire method through two ways:

1) by implement an interface.

2) by Method extension. (don't support in c++ and java)

It seems that we can use method extension to pretend that we have "implement" an interface, is it true?
If true, then what's the diff?

Comment: you need read msdn about [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No, not at all. You seem to be quite confused about those. Extension methods are *static* methods, that take an instance of an object to work on. They do not really extend the original class / interface at all, they're just a shortcut / syntactic sugar to enable you to use `.` notation instead of explicitly calling the static method.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are nothing but syntactic sugar to turn this:

```
static class Extensions {

    public static SomeMethod(Bar foo)

}
```

Into `foo.SomeMethod()` call on instances of Bar by marking the first argument with `this` in the declaration.  That's all it is.  The compiler will translate what looks like a call to an instance method into a call to the static method with the object instance as a parameter.

You aren't implementing anything, you are basically simply adding some behavior that *looks* like it's instance behavior, but it's really just a static method call.

Extension methods are basically like inheriting behavior, and not just signatures, from multiple interfaces.  The way .NET gets around the normal problems with multiple inheritance of concrete behavior is that the static methods don't actually belong to the interfaces: the belong to their own static classes.  So we can resolve the conflict by either segregating the methods into different namespaces, and including the one we want, or  fall back to the fully-qualified static method call that is unambiguous.